# Deducing template argument for nested template fails

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Ok, I read throught quite some “could not deduce template argument” questions but none seems to match my case — or I don't understand the answer…

There's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630941/failed-to-specialize-function-template) that I feel goes in the right direction, but I failed extracting the solution for my problem.

The stripped down code in my header looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class TemplateProblem
{
public:
    // Do I really need this or did I miss something from the STL?
    template<typename Tin, typename Tout>
    struct UnaryFunction : public std::unary_function<Tin, Tout>
    {
        virtual Tout operator()(Tin input) = 0;
    };

    template<typename Tin, typename Tout>
    struct StaticCast : public UnaryFunction<Tin, Tout>
    {
        virtual Tout operator()(Tin input)
        {
            return static_cast<Tout>(input);
        }
    };

private:
    T * const _data;
    T const _bias;

    template<typename Tin>
    void Init(Tin * data, int length, UnaryFunction<Tin, T> mapper, Tin bias);

public:
    template<typename Tin>
    TemplateProblem(Tin * data, int length, Tin bias = Tin());

    template<typename Tin>
    TemplateProblem(Tin * data, int length, UnaryFunction<Tin, T> mapper, Tin bias = T());
};

template<typename T>
template<typename Tin>
void TemplateProblem<T>::Init(Tin * data, int length, UnaryFunction<Tin, T> mapper, Tin bias)
{
    T mappedBias = mapper(bias);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        _data[i] = data[i] + mappedBias;
    }
}

template<typename T>
template<typename Tin>
TemplateProblem<T>::TemplateProblem(Tin * data, int length, UnaryFunction<Tin, T> mapper, Tin bias = T())
    : _data(new T[length]), _bias(bias)
{
    Init(data, length, mapper, bias);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename Tin>
TemplateProblem<T>::TemplateProblem(Tin * data, int length, Tin bias = T())
    : _data(new T[length]), _bias(bias)
{
    StaticCast<Tin, T> cast;
    Init(data, length, cast, bias);
}
```

I instantiate it like this:

```
unsigned char pixels[] = {23, 42, 65, 97};
TemplateProblem<int> tp(pixels, 4);
```

From VS2012 I get these messages:

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'void TemplateProblem<T>::Init(Tin *,int,TemplateProblem<T>::UnaryFunction<Tin,T>,Tin)' : could not deduce template argument for 'TemplateProblem<T>::UnaryFunction<Tin,T>' from 'TemplateProblem<T>::StaticCast<Tin,Tout>'    ...\templateproblem.h   62  1   TemplateProblem
Error   2   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void TemplateProblem<T>::Init(Tin *,int,TemplateProblem<T>::UnaryFunction<Tin,T>,Tin)' ...\templateproblem.h   62  1   TemplateProblem
```

The error also occurs when I move the two `struct`s out of the `class` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-template-and-parameter-deducing) suggests.

Comment: The instantiation code and the error messages are completely unrelated. The error talks about `StaticCast<Tin,Tout>`, but you don't have that anywhere in your instantiation code.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4psoUf$0 compiles fine... your code (before corrections) was not compilable.

Comment: @Xeo: StaticCast is used 3 lines from the bottom.

Comment: Oh, yeah, nvm, you have an extra `Init` function... I somehow mixed that up with the constructors.

Comment: Yes, in the original code everything's a bit more complicated and I wanted to share the code.

Comment: @ForEveR: The code you linked as references for all the `UnaryFunction`s, mine doesn't. Did that make the difference?

Comment: @primfaktor This makes differences, since objects of abstract classes can't be created. UnaryFunction<Tin, T> mapper - illegal. Anyway, gcc compiles fine.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 V 11.0.51106.01 Update 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error is not very helpful in indicating the actual problem.

The actual problem is that you pass `UnaryFunction<Tin, T>` by value to your `Init` function (and one of the constructors), but all instantiations of `UnaryFunction<>` result in an abstract class (which can not be passed by value).
The easy solution is to use pass-by-reference for `UnaryFunction`, so that `mapper` refers to the actual object passed in.

The typical solution in the STL for passing functors is to use a separate template argument, like this:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Tin, Tmapper>
void TemplateProblem<T>::Init(Tin * data, int length, Tmapper mapper, Tin bias)
{
    T mappedBias = mapper(bias);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        _data[i] = data[i] + mappedBias;
    }
}
```

Then you don't need the `UnaryFunctionL<>` base class. If an incompatible `mapper` is passed, this will be diagnosed when it is used in the body of the function.

Comment: That `Tmapper` template argument works *and* makes life easier. Thanks a lot!